# Use Certifikate from Adobe Air in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, air, certificate

First of all, i migrate with my apps from Flash to Java. 
I made certificate in Adobe Air for my Android App some time ago (kupony.p12).

Now i'm build my application in Eclipse (Java) but i can't sign my apk with my Old p12. 
When i try sign my apk with p12 then alias field is empty and eclipse show info "Invalid Keystore format".

What can i do with that?

http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/1076/flwm.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it.

1. Turn On "keytool" function. [instruction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=extCL1UU5wk)
2. Open cmd
3. With **cd** function open folder where is your [inputName].p12 Certificate.
4. Convert from P12 → JKS. [instruction](http://blog.ejbca.org/2008/02/converting-keystores-between-jks-and.html)

   keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [inputName].p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststoretype JKS -destkeystore [outputName].jks
5. Eclipse → YourPackage → right click → Android Tools → Export Signed Application Package.
6. Set Location and Password, Alias 1, set Destination APK File and Hit Finish.